# How can I force refresh map with traffic information?

Tags: caching, refresh, here-api, traffic

I have to use here-api and I follow this [tutorial](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/showing-traffic-information) to show a map with traffic information.
But when I have to re-show the map, the traffic information doesn't seem to be refreshed (in contrary to Here Map page)
How can I force to show traffic information in realtime ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The traffic tile provider should have a 'reload' method (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-provider-remotetileprovider.html#h-map-provider-remotetileprovider__reload):

```
var trafficLayer = defaultLayers.normal.traffic;
var trafficProvider = trafficLayer.getProvider();
trafficProvider.reload(false); // or true, depending on your requirements
```